# Masonry Grid Unwanted Space

Tags: javascript, html, css, masonry

```
$(".portfolio").imagesLoaded(function () {
    $(".portfolio").masonry({
        columnWidth: '.col-md-4.col-sm-6',
        itemSelector: '.col-md-4'
    });
});
```

It's getting better when you play around with your window. I do not want a space when you first open it.
http://webtehayat.net/demo/portfolio/

[image: grid]

Comment: You are using width with percentage. In this case, try to add percentPosition:true in the options!

Comment: thanks but now http://i.hizliresim.com/r3zR9z.jpg

Comment: It's getting better when you play around with your window.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have placed the `.col-md-4` class which has it's width as 33.333333% of the total available screen width.
You need to actually rethink the external and internal `div`'s space computations for the grid.

A quick & dirty fix is to put this in your CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    width: 34% !important;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

OR

You could add an additional 4th column instead of using just 3.

Comment: For bootstrap grid is not what you said.
I dont understand (" You could add an additional 4th column instead of using just 3.

 ")

Comment: Right now there are 3 columns in the right div, I'm suggesting to have a 4th column, all of them with the class `.col-md-3` insted of `.col-md-4`.